Regex to add spaces around all underscores in math equations (`$ ... $`)
I am trying to match all underscores included in math equations, surrounded by math delimiters $, and add spaces around them.
So, for example, in the math equation:
$(x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n)$

I want the final result to be
$(x _ 0, x _ 1, \dots, x _ n)$

So far, I have come up with a regex
\$([^\$]*)_([^\$]*)\$

and tried replacing with $$1 _ $2$.
It sort of works, but only matches a single underscore. In the above example, I got
$(x_0, x_1, \dots, x _ n)$

Is there a way to match every _ and replace them with _ all at once? If this is not possible in regex, I think I will have to look for other methods.
PS. The reason why I need this is because the markdown parser sometimes matches _ as emphasis and breaks the formatting of math equations. If anyone knows an efficient workaround to this (except using \_ - I use obsidian and this one breaks equations there) that would also be nice.

Which tool/programming language are you using to perform such a substitution?

I was using vscode's search and replace feature, since I can see the substitutions easily. I am open to other tools!

Does it mean you want to replace all underscores between $( and )$, not between just dollar symbols? In that case, the solution will become much trickier, like (?:\G(?!^)|\$\()(?:(?!\$\(|\)\$).)*?\K\s*_\s*(?=(?:(?!\$\(|\)\$).)*\)\$). See the regex demo. I'd suggest Notepad++ with this regex.

No, just between dollar symbols.

In VSCode, it supports non-fixed-width lookbehinds in single file search (for some reason global search doesn't support that), which means you could use following regex to target underscores enclosed by math delimiters $...$
(?<=\$\S[^$]*)\s?_\s?(?=[^$]*\S\$)

And replace it with
 _ 

Here's the demo
(?<=\$\S[^$]*)        # lookbehind, `$` followed by a non-white-space character, then without encountering a `$`
\s?_\s?               # underscore, with optional whitespaces around it
(?=[^$]*\S\$)         # lookahead, `$` preceded by a non-white-space character, without encountering a `$`


First of all, thanks for the answer. This is some dark magic regex to me, I wouldn't have able to come up with it myself. Also, sorry if my example was misleading, but there aren't necessarily parentheses around math equations. (As I wrote in the title) I tried to modify your answer but didn't quite get what I wanted.

I naively tried removing \( and \) from your example, but it matches underscores outside the math equation in your demo.

@zxcvber I see, I assume the math equation must be enclosed by $...$ without white spaces. If that's the case, see if the updated answer helps

Thanks it works. I wish it worked with global search, since I have so many files to replace. But I'll accept the answer anyways!
